# Chrome Driver not handling Alerts and constantly showing a notification about background apps when running selenium test

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Running selenium tests using chrome driver,  everytime the browser starts up I'm getting a notification balloon about added persistent background apps and then the test hangs it doesn't even appear to time out.

Anyone else seeing similar issues?

Comment: Noticed there's two different chrome driver downloads.  Only chromedriver2 is broken.

Comment: broken is incorrect - chromedriver2 is new, *buggy*, rewritten engine and I believe is still beta release (although I've not checked). It is not recommended for use. I would suggest you use the latest chromedriver release first - see if it makes a difference.